# "In valid argument" when removing permissions with Access Control Lists (ACL)?

Tags: acl, access-control

[This](https://portal.tacc.utexas.edu/tutorials/acls) website explains giving and removing the ACL. I have given the permission to another user, and now I want to remove it.

In the screenshot below, the `getfacl` is used to show that another user has been given the `r` and `x` accesses.

Then, I tried to use `setfacl -x u:userID:rx /directory/for/the/file/` to remove the permission. But I got the error message saying `setfacl: Option -x: Invalid argument near character 11`.

Can I ask how to properly remove the permissions?

[image]